# Grails 2.0 and xfire plugin exception

Tags: grails, cxf, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, xfire

I created simple Grails 2.0 service exposed with xfire plugin. With every call to this plugin I get exception, but WS is working fine. Is it normal? Only because of that server's log files gets huge.

The same error is with CXF plugin 0.7.0

Versions

```
Grails 2.0.0
Groovy 1.8.4
Xfire plugin 0.8.3
```

Grails commands:

```
install-plugin xfire
create-service com.pg.Test
```

Service:

```
package com.pg

class TestService {

    static expose=['xfire']

    def serviceMethod() {
        return "result"
    }
}
```

Grails Exception:

```
Error 2012-01-18 12:21:13,865 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-9] ERROR [/playground].[XFireServlet]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [XFireServlet] in context with path [/playground] threw exception
Message: No value for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@3853cb28] bound to thread ["http-bio-8080"-exec-9]
   Line | Method
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     ''
^   662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Full stacktrace:

```
    [#|2012-01-18T12:03:21.539+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=55;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[XFireServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet XFireServlet threw exception
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@6ef25f6b] bound to thread [http-thread-pool-8080(4)]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:209)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:232)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]
```

Comment: I'm not able to post an answer to this question so I put it as a comment. Issue is described here: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCXF-3?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

and can be resolved with Florian's modifications. Thanks!